# WinAPI and UTF-8 support

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, localization, utf-8

Quick question regarding UTF-8 support and various Win32 API's.

In a typical C++ MFC project, is it possible for MessageBox() to display a UTF-8 encoded string?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 11):

Quick answer: No.

Longer answer: It'll work if the string only contains regular ANSI characters, e.g US English, since these character codes are the same in UTF-8 and ANSI.

If non-ANSI characters are included, or any double-byte encoded characters, you'll need to transform to Unicode-16 using MultiByteToWideChar with CP_UTF8. Your program will also need to be compiled with UNICODE defined, or you can use the 'W' API calls - e.g. MessageBoxW.

(Note that functions taking a text argument such as MessageBox, CreateWindow map to either 'A' or 'W' versions depending on whether UNICODE is defined).

This may also be of use;

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Just a bit of terminology, but it's called UTF-16. There's no such thing as Unicde-16. :)

Comment: This Joel article is quite old and he really does downplay UTF-8 which is the most technically convenient Unicode encoding. His own ideas about finding the HTML meta tag only works with UTF-8 or some single byte (ASCII derived) encoding. Otherwise you get zero valued bytes all over the place which makes it difficult to look for '<' characters. In UTF-8 you can parse XML (and HTML) without worrying about Unicode at all since it guarantees you will see bytes < 127 only if they encode actual ASCII characters.

Comment: Also note that much of WinAPI is actually more like UCS-2, rather than UTF-16, in that at least some parts of WinAPI (which? I have no idea -- it all seems to be rather hit & miss) won't handle surrogate pairs correctly; in other words, they'll assume that UTF-16 is a fixed-width encoding.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx) with `CP_UTF8`.  See http://www.siao2.com/2006/10/11/816996.aspx for why A can't do it; W (UCS-2) is the only alternative.

Comment: +1 with little nitpicking: W version is UTF-16, not UCS-2 - it handles surrogate pairs as well.

Answer (score 4):

I use the ATL/MFC string conversion macros.  For example, if you have an ASCII string called `myUTF8Str` containing UTF8 chars:

```
::MessageBox(hWnd, CA2T(myUTF8Str, CP_UTF8), _T("Caption"), MB_OK);
```

Alternatively you can create an instance of the string, e.g.:

```
CA2T myConvertedString(myUTF8Str, CP_UTF8);
...
TRACE(_T("Converted: %s\n"), myUTF8Str.m_psz);
```

Note the `m_psz` member that allows read-only access to the raw string pointer.

You can also encode using `CT2A`, e.g.:

```
CT2A myEncodedString("Some UTF8", CP_UTF8);
```

If you don't use TEXT macros, then use CA2W, CW2A, etc.