# Get Strings in right encoding in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I asked a similar question before.
But I am still in trouble with encodings in c++.
I try to describe the problem as well as possible.

I have a c++ client, communicating with an c# service over TCP.
Now I need to display the Messages from the service in an Messagebox (Win32 API).
The Bytes, sended by the c# service are UTF-8 encoded.

Important to know, the c++ client will only be running on Windows Systems.

This is the code to receive the bytes and to display the Text:

```
    char buffer[1024];
    int receivedBytes = recv(socketHandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);
    char str[receivedBytes];
    for (int index = 0; index < receivedBytes; index++)
    {
        str[index] = buffer[index];
    }

    MessageBox(mainWindow, (LPCTSTR)str, (LPCTSTR) "Fehler", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
```

If the Text contains chatacters like üäö, they are not shown in the Messagebox the correct way.
What can I do to receive the message as UTF-8 String in c++?
Is there a possibility to convert the char[] to an UTF-8 String?

Thx for helping

Tobi

Comment: there are really two questions there: how do I handle utf8 string in tcp connections? and how do I handle utf8 string with winapi?

Comment: Maybe because you don't seem to set `result` anywhere?

Comment: maybe this question would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504779/winapi-and-utf-8-support

Comment: What is the point of copying buffer to str? It's sufficient if you just add a terminating 0 at the receivedBytes index, as in `buffer[receivedBytes] = 0;`. Apart from that, it's better to use `memcpy` for that purpose than copy byte by byte in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, that should not be result, but this is not the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display unicode characters in Windows, you need to translate UTF8 string into UTF16 (older UCS2), as this is the unicode standard Windows handles. You do that with [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Also make sure that the #define UNICODE is set before you include Windows headers, so that MessageBox points to MessageBoxW or use MessageBoxW explicitly.