# How to display message with special encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I am writing a program which I need to read text from a file and display this on the graph once mouse hover the datapoint. My problem is while I read the data from text file and show it on graph it shows some "?" instead of actual character. (cannot post images sorry)

here is my code to read from file and attempted to change encoding.(no success) :

```
string myString = File.ReadAllText(@"read.txt");

        Encoding enc_to = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        Encoding enc_from = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] InitialBytes =enc_from.GetBytes(myString);
        byte[] FinalBytes = Encoding.Convert(enc_from, enc_to, InitialBytes);
        string myMessage = enc_to.GetString(FinalBytes);
```

Please note that I dont want to show string as MessageBox.Show  rather I want to show it as tooltip.

here is the text in read.txt file :

```
3 stands of 5½"
```

here is the how it is shown  :

```
3 stands of 5�"
```

Comment: Why not just [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `Encoding.UTF8` as second parameter?

Comment: encodings are a pain! especially the windows standard one. can you not reformat the file to utf16?

Comment: check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966156/get-strings-in-right-encoding-in-c

Comment: Why bring C++ to a C# fight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Encoding.Default:`

```
string myString = File.ReadAllText(@"read.txt",Encoding.Default);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works as a charm. For one simple advice I searched a lot on google. Thanks Moez :)