# Encoding Vietnamese characters from ISO88591, UTF8, UTF16BE, UTF16LE, UTF16 to Hex and vice versa using C++

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, c++14, utf

I have edited my post. Currently what I'm trying to do is to encode an input string from the user and then convert it to Hex formats. I can do it properly if it does not contain any Vietnamese character.
If my inputString is "Hello". But when I try to input a string such as "Tôi", I don't know how to do it.

```
    enum Encodings { USASCII, ISO88591, UTF8, UTF16BE, UTF16LE, UTF16, BIN, OCT, HEX };

    switch (Encodings)
        {
        case USASCII:
            ASCIIToHex(inputString, &ascii); //hello output 48656C6C6F
            return new ByteField(ascii.c_str());
        case ISO88591:
            ASCIIToHex(inputString, &ascii);//hello output 48656C6C6F
                                              //tôi output 54F469
            return new ByteField(ascii.c_str());
        case UTF8:
            ASCIIToHex(inputString, &ascii);//hello output 48656C6C6F
                                           //tôi output 54C3B469
            return new ByteField(ascii.c_str());
        case UTF16BE:
            ToUTF16(inputString, &ascii, Encodings);//hello output 00480065006C006C006F
                                                    //tôi output 005400F40069
            return new ByteField(ascii.c_str());
        case UTF16:
        ToUTF16(inputString, &ascii, Encodings);//hello output FEFF00480065006C006C006F
                                                //tôi output FEFF005400F40069
            return new ByteField(ascii.c_str());
        case UTF16LE:
            ToUTF16(inputString, &ascii, Encodings);//hello output 480065006C006C006F00
                                                    //tôi output 5400F4006900
            return new ByteField(ascii.c_str());
        }

void StringUtilLib::ASCIIToHex(std::string s, std::string * result)
{
    int n = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = s[i];
        long val = long(c);
        std::string bin = "";
        while (val > 0)
        {
            (val % 2) ? bin.push_back('1') :
                bin.push_back('0');
            val /= 2;
        }
        reverse(bin.begin(), bin.end());
        result->append(ConvertBinToHex(bin));
    }
}

std::string ToUTF16(std::string s, std::string * result, int encodings) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (encodings == UTF16) {
        result->append("FEFF");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int val = int(s[i]);
        std::string bin = "";
        while (val > 0)
        {
            (val % 2) ? bin.push_back('1') :
                bin.push_back('0');
            val /= 2;
        }
        reverse(bin.begin(), bin.end());
        if (encodings == UTF16 || encodings == UTF16BE) {
            result->append("00" + ConvertBinToHex(bin));
        }
        if (encodings == UTF16LE) {
            result->append(ConvertBinToHex(bin) + "00");
        }

    }
}

std::string ConvertBinToHex(std::string str) {
    long long temp = atoll(str.c_str());
    int dec_value = 0;
    int base = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (temp) {
        int last_digit = temp % 10;
        temp = temp / 10;
        dec_value += last_digit * base;
        base = base * 2;
    }
    char hexaDeciNum[10];
    while (dec_value != 0)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        temp = dec_value % 16;
        if (temp < 10)
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 48;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            hexaDeciNum[i] = temp + 55;
            i++;
        }
        dec_value = dec_value / 16;
    }
    str.clear();
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        str = str + hexaDeciNum[j];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: What's `s`? ---

Comment: It's my input string. Sorry...

Comment: Yes, but what type is it? You seem to be trying to store UTF-32 into an `std::string`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I extract each character from my std::string to val(decimal value) and then I convert from decimal to binary. But when my input string contains character such as "Á" the value of val is negative (-64)

Comment: What do you mean, you have [Windows-1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258) and would like to encode it to UTF-8 ?

Comment: TBH, I'm having a hard time to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to display the binary representation of a vietnamese UTF 8 char? This will fail if you try this with a single char, since UTF8 is a multi-byte char set.
May be this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47238698/2328447 may help you?

Comment: What I want to achieve is that I want to get a binary value of a Vietnamese character such as "À"? Because I'm new to C++ but I get stuck with these Encode thing so the way I make question can be a little hard to understand

Comment: No wonder you are stuck. C++ has an extremely poor support for Unicode and internationalisation out of the box. Why do you need hexadecimal or binary values though?

Comment: I'm developing a program that supports Porsche but under the C++ platform. It's a part of my work. I'm main in Java

Comment: "I'm developing a program that supports Porsche". That's not really relevant. You may be supporting Boeing ot AEG or Samsung for all I know. Why do you need hexadecimal or binary values?

Comment: Oh sorry. It's a part of my StringUtilLib extensions for that program. Which I have to Encode user input value to USASCII, ISO88591, UTF8, UTF16BE, UTF16LE, UTF16, BIN[0-1], OCT,[0-7], HEX[0-9A-F]. And I got stuck when I want to encode a Vietnamese input string to each of them except BIN, OCT, and HEX.

Comment: In order to encode something, you need to have something to encode first. And you need to know exactly what you have. Forget emcoding your stuff for a moment. You want to understand what stuff you've got in the first place. How are you getting user input?

Comment: I think that I have figured out what I'm trying to do from the beginning. The input string and Encodings enum is the type of the input String. What I have to do is to convert from UTF8, UTF16,etc... to Hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is completely unclear. To encode something you need an input right? So when you say *"Encoding Vietnamese Character to UTF8, UTF16"* what's your input string and what's the encoding before converting to UTF-8/16? How do you input it? From file or console?

And why on earth are you converting to binary and then to hex? You can print directly to binary and hex from the bytes, no need to convert from binary to hex. Note that converting to binary like that is fine for testing but vastly inefficient in production code. I also don't know what you mean by *"But what if my letter is "Á" or "À" which is a Vietnamese letter I cannot get the value of it"*. Please show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the input/output

---

But I think you just want to output the UTF encoded bytes from a string literal in the source code like "ÁÀ". In that case it isn't called "encoding a string" but just "outputting a string"

Both `Á` and `À` in Unicode can be represented by [precomposed characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) (U+00C1 and U+00C0) or [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) (A + U+0301 ◌́/U+0300 ◌̀). You can switch between them by selecting *"Unicode dựng sẵn"* or *"Unicode tổ hợp"* in Unikey. Suppose you have those characters in string literal form then `std::string str = "ÁÀ"` contains a series of bytes that corresponds to the above letters in the source file encoding. So depending on which encoding you save the *.cpp file as (CP1252, CP1258, UTF-8...), the output byte values will be different

To force UTF-8/16/32 encoding you just need to use the `u8`, `u` and `U` suffix respectively, along with the correct type (`char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t` or `std::u8string`/`std::u16string`/`std::u32string`)

```
std::u8string  utf8  = u8"ÁÀ";
std::u16string utf16 = u"ÁÀ";
std::u32string utf32 = U"ÁÀ";
```

Then just use `c_str()` to get the underlying buffers and print the bytes. In C++14 `std::u8string` is not available yet so just save the file as UTF-8 and use `std::string`. Similarly you can read `std::u*string` directly from `std::cin` to print the encoding of a user-input string

## Edit:

To convert between UTF encodings use the standard [`std::codecvt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), [`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert), [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16)...

Working on non-Unicode encodings is trickier and needs some external library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) or OS-dependent APIs

- [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) and [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) on Windows
- [`iconv`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/iconv.3.html) on Linux

Limiting to ISO-8859-1 makes it easier but you still need many lookup tables, and there's no way to convert other encodings to ASCII without loss of information

Comment: I need to convert it, not to print it. The input from the user is a String such as "I am Vietnamese" and then I have to convert it to USASCII, ISO88591, UTF8, UTF16BE, UTF16LE, UTF16. I have done it, but when the input string contains Vietnamese character I cannot convert it to USASCII, ISO88591, UTF8, UTF16BE, UTF16LE, UTF16. I can do it in Java but I can't do it in C++, which is the main problem.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm "The input from the user is a String" but which encoding? As I said above you must have an input encoding in order to convert to another. Anyway just use `MultiByteToWideChar`/`WideCharToMultiByte` on Windows and ` iconv` on Linux

Comment: thanks for helping me out. Do you have any tutorials or examples in using those 2 API??

Comment: just read the links to the documentation I gave you. Encoding is a huge topic and relates to a lot of legacy things that aren't used anymore so it'll be easier to deal with it using a framework like .NET or Java. C++ itself doesn't do anything on encoding and just gained Unicode support recently

Comment: I have a misunderstanding of the situation. The Enum Encodings is the encoding type that the user wants to convert the string from to Hex

Answer (score 1):

-64 is the correct representation of  À if you are using signed char and CP1258. If you want a positive number you need to cast to `unsigned char` first.

If you are indeed using CP1258, you are probably on Windows. To convert your input string to UTF-16, you probably want to use a Windows platform API such as [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) which accepts a code page parameter (of course you have to use the correct code page). Alternatively you may try a standard function like [`mbstowcs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs)  but you need to set up your locale correctly before using it.

You might find it easier to switch to wide characters throughout your application, and avoid most transcoding.

As a side note, converting an integer to binary only to convert that to hexadecimal is not an easy or efficient way to display a hexadecimal representation of an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will give a try with MultiByteToWideChar API

Comment: No one uses CP1258 in Vietnam. Most don't even know or heard about CP1258. They just select Unicode while typing

Comment: @phuclv I bet you can explain how À ended up being -64 then.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't see the comment about that value, but most Vietnamese use Windows in the US locale, and CP1252 in that locale maps ÀÁ to 0xC0 0xC1 just like CP1258 which are -64 and -63 respectively

Comment: I not really good at these Encodings but when I test it in Java I get the result and then I come back with my C++ and make my program have the same result. In Java or C#, most of the Encodings is already support in the core Library.

Comment: @phuclv one cannot use CP1252 so that À results in 0xC0 *and* type all Vietnamese characters at the same time. One of the assumptions has to go.

Comment: @n.m. people don't type Vietnamese in the console, since no one uses a proper IME but an external keyboard hooking software named Unikey to type Vietnamese that doesn't work correctly with conhost. I bet when the OP runs `chcp` it'll return 1252. And people don't use Vietnamese interface in their PCs. Everyone uses Windows in English regardless of their English level and only types Vietnamese in text editors or browsers where **code page plays zero role**

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm note that both Java and C# use UTF-16 in two-byte characters natively. In C++ if you are on Windows you can do much the same thing, you just need to forget that char exists and use wchar_t and wstring throughout. If you are doing console I/O you basically have no other choice.

Comment: @phuclv this is all fine and dandy but your UI language and your console code page need not be connected in any way. À as 0xC0 cannot possibly come from UTF-8. It could possibly come from UTF-16 but then to end up as -64 it needs to be really screwed up. I think I will stop guessing at this point. It isn't really possible to say anything definite without knowing a lot more about OP's setup.

Comment: I know they're not connected but it's highly likely because the OP saved the source file in the default CP1252 code point instead of UTF-8 which produces the output bytes like that. And you don't need to use `wchar_t`. On newer Windows 10 the UTF-8 65001 locale works just fine

Comment: @phuclv "On newer Windows 10 the UTF-8 65001 locale works just fine" Don't know what you mean. It' not a locale, it's a code page. And I could never make it work. Maybe I have missed an update a week ago or something.

Comment: It's a codepage, but the settings to enable it is inside the locale dialog box so many people have addressed it as "locale"